# /proc/kcore very big

Tags: disk-management

I am running Ubuntu 11.04 and I ran a very RAM intensive program.

When I try to log in after reboot, I receive an error message:

> The configuration defaults for Gnome Power Management have not been
>   installed correctly

And I cannot log in, except as root.

When I log as root I get the message:

```
File system root has only 0 bytes disk space remaining. 

/dev/sda1             48256340  48015552         0 100% /
none                  12359144       716  12358428   1% /dev
none                  12366864        24  12366840   1% /dev/shm
none                  12366864       356  12366508   1% /var/run
none                  12366864         0  12366864   0% /var/lock
/dev/sda6            890105868 215415664 629475384  26% /home
```

The culprit seems to be `/proc/kcore` with a size of 128Tb (my HD is 100Tb with 24Gb RAM). I understand that this file is a virtual file and contains the RAM the kernel can allocate and that I cannot delete it.

Do you have idea on how to solve this problem ?

Many thanks !

Comment: A have a "file" of 128T too in `proc` and my system works well as far as I know :-)

Comment: My /proc/kcore is 140TB on my computer but I only have an 512GB hard drive with 4GB RAM. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you understand what you say you understand, then you would know that this is not a/the problem.  Nothing in /proc takes up any space on the disk.  You need to look elsewhere for what is taking up space.  The same goes for /sys, and /dev.

Comment: @pasta: FYI `/proc`, `/dev` and `/sys` live in the RAM.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for large files in /home(this contains all users' home directories) ad delete them. If you have trouble due to the kernel or `sudo rm` not allowing this, try using a LiveCD, mounting your partition that contains `/home` and deleting the files that way. Also, if you use the Live CD, you can use Baobab(Accessories>Disk Usage Analyzer) to help track down the offending file. Good luck.